# data stored in database doesnt load in textarea

Tags: php, wordpress

im a newbie in `php` and `wordpress`, I've doing this hello world plugin in which it stores data through `wordrepss`' database, one thing that wrong is that when i click on the button  it doesnt display inside the text area. What am i doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
add_action('admin_menu','hello_world_plugin');
function hello_world_plugin (){
    add_options_page('Hello Page','Hello Submenu','manage_options',__FILE__,'Hello_Admin');
}

//Insert Data
global $wpdb;
$first = $_POST['firstname'];
$last = $_POST['lastname'];
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $wpdb->insert("wp_options", array(
            "option_name" => $first,
            "option_value" => $last
            )
        );
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Data Submitted!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
// Display Data
    if(isset($_POST['Display'])) {
            $result = $wpdb->get_results (
                "
                SELECT * FROM wp_options
                WHERE option_id > '209'
                "
                );
    }
?>

<?php   


function Hello_Admin() {

    echo '<div class = "wrap">';
    echo '<h4> Hello World Plugin </h4>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<form action = "" method = "POST">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>';
    echo '<input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value ="Submit to (wp_options)" class = "button-primary"><br><br>';
    echo '<input type = "submit" name = "Display" value ="Display Data from (wp_options)" class = "button-primary"/><br><br>';
    echo '</form><br>';

?>
     //it should display here the i click the button display
    **<textarea cols="50" rows="10"><?php print_r($result); ?></textarea>**

<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the save data in option table. chack this code for save data in option table using `add_option` funtion .
[click here for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
       // eg. add_option( $option, $value, $deprecated, $autoload ); 
        add_option( 'hello_first_name', '$first', '', 'yes' );
        add_option( 'hello_last_name', '$lasr', '', 'yes' );
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Data Submitted!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

also change in get option data using `get_option` like bellow.
[click here for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

```
if(isset($_POST['Display'])) {
        //eg.   get_option( $option, $default );
        $firstname=get_option( 'hello_first_name');
        $lastname=get_option( 'hello_last_name');
    }
```

now display in text area like bellow

```
if(isset($_POST['Display'])) {
<textarea cols="50" rows="10"><?php echo $firstname.$lastnamew; ?></textarea> 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, however the thing i want to accomplish is to print_r($result) since it's an array to be inside the text area. it doesnt load.